# Why is React component only working after I refresh page?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a component called Tools which is accessed when I am on the route `tools/:id`. On this page, I have buttons with `Links` to this page, but it passes in a different id to the URL when clicked so that a different tool will be shown.

The getTool method just returns the correct component, and the component will only have one thing, an iFrame to show a calculator from another website.

So when I go back and forth between tools, the tools aren't loading until I click refresh. Otherwise, I get an error that says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`. This is because I have `document.getElementById('calc-SOME-NUMBER')` but SOME_NUMBER is still referring to the last tool I was on. And this statement is within each tool and you can this below in `BCalc`.

I've checked the state, and when I go back and forth between tools, everything is correct; the correct tool is placed in the reducer. Any idea why this is happening? I was using `history.go()` as a workaround because I can't see any reason it still is lingering on to the old tools id.

```
const Tool = ({
  getContent,
  closeContent,
  content: { content, loading, contents },
  user,
  match,
}) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollToTop();
    getContent(match.params.id);
    return () => {
      logView(user, match.params.id, "tool");
      closeContent();
      history.go(); // doesn't work without this line
    };
  }, [getContent, closeContent, match.params.id, user]);

  let ToolComponent;

  const listItemStyle = { paddingTop: "40px", paddingBottom: "40px" };

  return loading || content === null ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : (
    <Container
      style={{ marginTop: "3%" }}
      fluid="true"
      className="contentCardBody"
    >
      <Card>
       <Card.Body>
          {(ToolComponent = getTool(content.content_id.path))}
                <ToolComponent />
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </Container>
  );
};

Tool.propTypes = {
  content: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  user: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  getContent: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  closeContent: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  content: state.content,
  user: state.auth.user,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getContent,
  closeContent,
})(Tool);
```

Also, here is an example of what is returned from getTool():

```
const BCalc = () => {
  const eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? 'addEventListener' : 'attachEvent';
  const eventer = window[eventMethod];
  const messageEvent = eventMethod === 'attachEvent' ? 'onmessage' : 'message';
  eventer(
    messageEvent,
    (e) => {
      if (e.origin === 'https://EXAMPLE.com') {
        if (e.data.startsWith('height;')) {
          document.getElementById('calc-SOME_NUMBER').style.height = `${e.data.split('height;')[1]}px`;
        } else if (e.data.startsWith('url;')) {
          window.location.href = e.data.split('url;')[1];
        }
      }
    },
    !1,
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <iframe
        id="calc-SOME_NUMBER"
        src="https://EXAMPLE_CALC"
        title="tool"
        scrolling="no"
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          border: 'none',
          marginTop: '-2%',
          zIndex: '-1',
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default BCalc;
```

Comment: You need to wrap your eventlistener in an useEffect hook. Right now you're trying to attach it before the iframe has been mounted.

Comment: I tried but still got the same error